# Как в данном случае корректно заставить работать функцию get() в библиотеке tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

При использовании виджета 'ut1', вызывая функцию Write, получаю ошибку: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'.
Как в данном случае корректно заставить работать метод get().

```
#roadmap
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog



def create_frame(label_text):
    frame = ttk.Frame(borderwidth=1, relief=SOLID)
    label = ttk.Label(frame, text=label_text).pack()
    input_variable = StringVar()
    entry = ttk.Entry(frame, textvariable=input_variable).pack()
    return frame, entry



def win():

    def Write():
        print(task.get())

    window = Tk()
    window.title('Roadmap')
    window.geometry('500x250')
    task = create_frame('Глобальная задача')
    task.pack(anchor=NW, fill=X, padx=5, pady=5)
    ut1 = Button(text='Сохранить', command=Write).pack()
    window.mainloop()





def main():
    win()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Я не знаю как вы не получаете ошибку:

   > AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'pack'

   На строчке:

   ```py
   task = create_frame('Глобальная задача').pack(anchor=NW, fill=X, padx=5, pady=5)
   ```

   Я лично получаю, т.к. функция `create_frame` возвращает `entry`, который равен результату функции `pack`, а функция `pack` возвращает `None`. (и по идее вы должны были, хмм)

   В вашем случае можно просто вернуть из функции `ttk.Entry(frame, textvariable=input_variable)` т.к. далее вы его упаковываете вне функции этой функции.

   P.s. я думаю вы так же забыли упаковать `frame`
2. Ошибка из вопроса, аналогична ошибке выше. После того как вы получаете что-то из `create_frame` вы его так же упаковываете и результат функции `pack` сохраняете в `task`.

   Вам нужно отдельно сохранить `task`, как результат `create_frame` и отдельно для него вызвать функцию `pack`

   ```py
   task = create_frame('Глобальная задача')
   task.pack(anchor=NW, fill=X, padx=5, pady=5)
   ```

---

Код с комментариями:

```py
def create_frame(label_text):
    # Сначала сохраняем в переменную, если вам нужен потом этот виджет
    frame = ttk.Frame(borderwidth=1, relief=SOLID)
    # Потом вызываете pack
    frame.pack()
    label = ttk.Label(frame, text=label_text).pack()
    input_variable = StringVar()
    # Так же сохраняем в переменную
    entry = ttk.Entry(frame, textvariable=input_variable)
    # У entry можно не вызывать pack, т.к. вы его вызовите в функции win
    return frame, entry
```

Уже результат функции принимаете так:

```py
frame, task = create_frame('Глобальная задача')
```

Comment: Да, в функции create_frame я забыл указать return frame.

Comment: @alexsandr8433 главное возвращайте именно `frame`, а не результат функции `pack` (то есть `None` всегда). Если мой ответ вам помог, пожалуйста примите его как правильный, нажав на галочку слева от ответа.

Comment: я вернул frame, пересохранил task.pack(...), но все равно получаю ошибку при вызове Write
AttributeError: 'Frame' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: @alexsandr8433 ах да, у `Frame` нет `get`. Вам нужно возвращать именно `Entry`. Если вам нужно так же и `Frame`, можете вернуть сразу и то, и то. Главное в `task` поместите `Entry`.

Comment: Можно пример, я не совсем понимаю как это сделать.
Я возвращаю entry, добавляю еще один параметр в функцию create_frame, но не понимаю как мне вызвать переданный параметр entry.
Получается: def create_frame(label_text, params): 
....
entry = ttk.Entry(frame, textvariable=input_variable, params=params).pack()
return frame, entry

Comment: @alexsandr8433 вернуть `return frame, entry`. Принять `frame, task = create_frame('Глобальная задача')`

Comment: Можете пожалуйста объяснить на примере кода (я исправил его в шапке, с учетом корректировок)?

Comment: @alexsandr8433 я же выше все написал. Как вернуть и как их принять из функции. Единственное, что `entry = ttk.Entry(frame, textvariable=input_variable, params=params)`, а после уже (на новой строчке) пишите `entry.pack()`. Функция `pack` ничего не возвращает. По этому `entry` у вас будет равен `None`, из-за чего у вас ошибка и возникает. Тоже самое с `frame`. `pack` ничего не возвращает. Если вы дальше хотите обращаться к виджету, то сначала его нужно сохранить, в переменную, а потом отдельно вызвать `pack`. И не изменяйте пожалуйста код в вопросе.

Comment: @alexsandr8433 добавил код в ответ.